# Difference between git rebase and git reset

Tags: git, git-rebase

Say I have this:

```
A - B - C - E - F    [integration]
 \
  G - H - I          [feature]
```

after commit `I`, we rebase with with integration:

```
git fetch origin
git rebase integration
```

so now we have:

```
A - B - C - E - F    [integration]
 \
  B - C - E - F - G - H - I          [feature]
```

and then say we merge the feature branch into integration, we then have:

```
A - B - C - E - F - G - H - I   [integration]
 \
  B - C - E - F - G - H - I          [feature]
```

(I think that is right), but I don't see how that is any different than not rebasing at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "git reset" vs "git rebase"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225293/what-is-the-difference-between-git-reset-vs-git-rebase)

Comment: `git fetch` and then `git rebase integration` will most probably be a no-op because fetch only updates refs for remote branches. You would need to do `git rebase origin/integration` to really rebase your feature branch onto new changes introduced on integration.

Comment: Definite duplicate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your drawing is misleading you.

Remember these things:

- A commit's "true name" is its hash ID.
- Each commit stores the hash ID of its parent commit, or for a merge commit, all of its parents.
- No commit can ever be changed at all, but commits *can* be copied to new replacements.

If it helps, think of commits as big, solid things: bricks and beams making up a building, for instance.  (Like oversized Lego bricks, each brick has some connector(s) to some other brick, and we plug our bricks together to make chains.  These connections are via the hash IDs: they come out of the child commit and point towards the parent.)

Branch *names*, on the other hand, are very light weight items.  They're like sticky notes that you slap on a commit, then peel off later and slap on a different commit.

So if you have this:

```
A <-B <-C <-E <-F   <-- integration
 \
  G <-H <-I   <-- feature
```

you cannot get your second picture, because existing commit `G` records `A`'s hash ID.  You *cannot* have a `G` that has `F` as its parent.  You also *should* not draw a commit twice, if at all possible: commits are unique things, there's only one commit `G`.

#### `git cherry-pick` is the building block for *copying* commits

Often, we find ourselves in a situation in which we have a commit like `G` that's OK as it is, but we'd like it more if it were a little bit different.  We'd like a new copy that's *like* `G`, but has `F` as its parent, and has a different source tree snapshot than the original `G` too.  Let's call the new commit `G'` to distinguish it from `G` but remind us that it's a lot *like* `G`.  We want the *difference between* `F` and `G'` to be the same as the *difference between* `A` and `G`, thereby accounting for any changes needed because of commits `B-C-E-F` too.  So what we want is a commit graph that looks like this:

```
              G'  <-- new-and-improved-feature
             /
A--B--C--E--F   <-- integration
 \
  G--H--I   <-- feature
```

If we then copy commit `H` to a *new and improved* `H'`, and copy `I` to a *new and improved* `I'`, we get this:

```
              G'-H'-I'  <-- new-and-improved-feature
             /
A--B--C--E--F   <-- integration
 \
  G--H--I   <-- feature
```

#### `git reset` moves labels

What `git reset` does—well, one of several things it can do, but this is what we do with it now—is to move the branch name sticky-labels.

There is one sticky-label on which we wrote the word `feature`.  That sticky-label is attached to commit `I` right now.  But we just used `git cherry-pick` three times, to *copy* the `G-H-I` sequence to the `G'-H'-I'` sequence, in our new and improved setup.

If we now have Git peel the label `feature` off commit `I`, and paste it onto commit `I'` instead, we get this:

```
              G'-H'-I'  <-- feature (HEAD), new-and-improved-feature
             /
A--B--C--E--F   <-- integration
 \
  G--H--I   <-- ORIG_HEAD
```

To make that happen, we run: `git checkout feature; git reset new-and-improved-feature`.

The `git reset` command sets this special name `ORIG_HEAD` to remember where `feature` used to go.  Now the label `feature` is attached to commit `I'`, but there are ways to find `I`, including this `ORIG_HEAD` trick.

(We no longer need the "new and improved feature" label, so we can delete it now.)

Note that *no commit has changed*.  The original `G` is still in the repository.  Running `git log ORIG_HEAD`, we can still see it, at least until we do another Git command that uses `ORIG_HEAD` to remember some other commit.  We'll see `I`, then `H`, then `G`.  We can also use the *reflog* for `feature` to find the hash ID for commits `G`, `H`, and `I`.  As long as we have the hash ID or a name for the hash ID, we can find the commit.  (Those reflog entries eventually expire—they have a date stamp, and after a month or three, Git removes the reflog entry.)

If we use the name `feature`, though, we *find the new copies* instead of the original commits.  This makes it *seem like* the commits have changed, as long as we don't pay close attention and notice that in fact, these are *new* commits.

The bottom line is this: **After we copy the commits**, if we use `git reset` to abandon the originals in favor of the new-and-improved copies, we'll see only the new-and-improved copies, and we can *act like* the commits have changed.  The commits haven't changed, and if anyone really looks closely, they will discover our secret, but **if someone else never knew about the originals** they cannot discover that these are  <strike>cheap knock-offs</strike>  improved copies.

#### `git rebase` = cherry-pick plus reset

This brings us to the conclusion: *`git rebase` is fundamentally `git cherry-pick` of some set of commits **followed by** `git reset`*.  That is, we start by *copying* commits to new and—we hope—improved versions; then we use `git reset` to attempt to trick everyone into using the improved commits in place of the originals.

*Anyone who still has the originals will not be fooled!*  If someone else—some other Git repository—still has the original commits, we must convince *them* to switch to the new improved commits too.  But if we're the only ones with access to the commits, we only have to fool ourselves, which is probably easier.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, what I've read about and found is that you only do a rebase if you would like to erase your commit history. Git reset is going to change your reference history in your reference files.

I found a great explanation of the difference between the two on stack overflow: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225293/what-is-the-difference-between-git-reset-vs-git-rebase)

I hope that helps to clarify which option is the best tool for the job under which circumstance.